# Power Automate - Get value of one column from array created by Get Items

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, power-automate, flow, power-platform

In my flow, I need to get the value of a specific column (ApprovalType) for an item in a SharePoint list.

First, I use Get Items with a filter query which gets to one item. This produces an array. This list is updated frequently, so I can't use Get Item with an item ID.

How can I get the value of the approval column from the output of the Get Items? The output is below, with user info changed.

```
    "@odata.etag": "\"3\"",
    "ItemInternalId": "1",
    "ID": 1,
    "Title": "Files",
    "Department": {
        "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Azure.Connectors.SharePoint.SPListExpandedReference",
        "Id": 8,
        "Value": "Legal"
    },
    "Department#Id": 8,
    "ApprovalType": {
        "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Azure.Connectors.SharePoint.SPListExpandedReference",
        "Id": 0,
        "Value": "First to respond"
    },
    "ApprovalType#Id": 0,
    "Approvers": [
        {
            "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Azure.Connectors.SharePoint.SPListExpandedUser",
            "Claims": "i:0#.f|membership|user1@tcf.com",
            "DisplayName": "User1",
            "Email": "user1@tcf.com",
            "Picture": "https://exampleurl.com",
            "Department": "Information Systems",
            "JobTitle": "Help Desk II"
        },
        {
            "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Azure.Connectors.SharePoint.SPListExpandedUser",
            "Claims": "i:0#.f|membership|user2",
            "DisplayName": "User2",
            "Email": "user2",
            "Picture": "https://exampleurl.com",
            "Department": null,
            "JobTitle": null
        },
        {
            "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Azure.Connectors.SharePoint.SPListExpandedUser",
            "Claims": "i:0#.f|membership|user3",
            "DisplayName": "User3",
            "Email": "user3",
            "Picture": "https://exampleurl.com",
            "Department": "Information Systems",
            "JobTitle": "Help Desk II"
        }
    ],
    "Approvers@odata.type": "#Collection(Microsoft.Azure.Connectors.SharePoint.SPListExpandedUser)",
    "Approvers#Claims": [
        "i:0#.f|membership|user1@tcf.com",
        "i:0#.f|membership|user2",
        "i:0#.f|membership|user3"
    ],
    "Approvers#Claims@odata.type": "#Collection(String)",
    "Modified": "2023-07-10T15:48:25Z",
    "Created": "2023-06-21T15:00:22Z",
    "Author": {
        "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Azure.Connectors.SharePoint.SPListExpandedUser",
        "Claims": "i:0#.f|membership|user2",
        "DisplayName": "User2",
        "Email": "user2",
        "Picture": "https://exampleurl.com",
        "Department": null,
        "JobTitle": null
    },
    "Author#Claims": "i:0#.f|membership|user2",
    "Editor": {
        "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Azure.Connectors.SharePoint.SPListExpandedUser",
        "Claims": "i:0#.f|membership|user2",
        "DisplayName": "User1",
        "Email": "user2",
        "Picture": "https://exampleurl.com",
        "Department": null,
        "JobTitle": null
    },
    "Editor#Claims": "i:0#.f|membership|user2",
    "{Identifier}": "Lists%252fApproverMatrix%252f1_.000",
    "{IsFolder}": false,
    "{Thumbnail}": {
        "Large": null,
        "Medium": null,
        "Small": null
    },
    "{Link}": "https://exampleurl.com",
    "{Name}": "Files",
    "{FilenameWithExtension}": "Files",
    "{Path}": "Lists/ApproverMatrix/",
    "{FullPath}": "Lists/ApproverMatrix/1_.000",
    "{HasAttachments}": false,
    "{VersionNumber}": "3.0"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are sure you will always get only "one item" in response array from "Get items" action, you can use an expression like below to get the value of Approval Type choice column:

```
outputs('Get_items')?['body/value'][0]['ApprovalType']?['Value']
```

Where `ApprovalType` is the internal name of your list column. You can get the internal name of your column by following this article: [How to find the Internal name of columns in SharePoint Online?](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2023/04/17/how-to-find-the-internal-name-of-sharepoint-columns/)

**Flow**:

[image]

**Output**:

[image]

---

**Solution 2**:

Use Apply to each action > use output from get items action as input to apply to each > add compose action inside apply to each and select Approval Type Value from dynamic content like:

[image]

Comment: That provided exactly what I needed - thank you! Specifically, adding "?['Value'] to the output.

Answer (score -1):

One way would be to add a `Get Item` action after your Get Items action and for the ID set the expression to:

> `outputs('Get_items')?['body/value'][0]?['ID']`

`('Get_items')` This would need to be updated with the correct name of your Get Items action if you've renamed it

`[0]` This is the first (and hopefully only) item in your get items array

`?['ID']` This specifies to use the value of the ID field

After that, you can use the outputs of the Get Item action as required.